# Handling dates and times between C# API and Typescript

Tags: c#, typescript, datetime, timezone, datetimeoffset

I am having trouble correctly transporting my date and timezone to my backend. I am using a DateTimeOffset in the backend and a TypeScript date in the frontend. I attempted to convert the date to the correct format using moment.js, but unfortunately, I was unsuccessful. Can you please assist me with this issue? I am unsure whether to convert the backend DateTimeOffset to a string, as it is difficult to implement and not the optimal solution.  Unfortunately, my research has not yielded any helpful results. I am using the datetime-local text field from Fluent UI, which requires me to convert the date format multiple times.

Frontend:

```
    //model
    export interface Setting {
            validFrom?: Date;
            validTo?: Date;
        }
    //apiService
    public async createSetting(setting: Setting): Promise<any> {
    let postUrl = ``
    try {
      return await axios.post(postUrl, setting)
    } catch (ex) {
      return ex
    }  
}


// Formating for saving
        const parseDateForSave = (dateString?: string) => {
            console.log("parseDateForSave: " +dateString);
            return dateString ? moment.tz(dateString, "Europe/Berlin").toDate() : undefined;
        };


//format for displaying in textfield
        const formatDateForDisplay = (dateTime?: Date | string) => {
            if (!dateTime) {
                return '';
            }
            const date = typeof dateTime === 'string' ? new Date(dateTime) : dateTime;
            return moment(date).format('YYYY-MM-DDTHH:mm');
        };
```

The console in the frontend shows it to me as expected, but I have read that it already performs formatting.

```
F12 console: setting from: 2023-12-11 08:49:00 +01:00 to 2023-12-17 09:49:00 +01:00
```

Backend:

```
   [HttpPost]
    [Route("")]
    public async Task<ActionResult<Setting>> CreateSetting([FromBody] Setting setting)
    {
        try
        {
            .....
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
....
        }
    }

    public class Setting : xxx
{
    public DateTimeOffset? ValidFrom { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? ValidTo { get; set; }
    public DateTimeOffset? LastUpdate { get; set; }}
```

The LastUpdate Date appears one hour too early in the backend due to the absence of the time zone. In the backend, I set the LastUpdate Date using DateTimeOffset.Now. This writes the value, including the time zone, correctly into the database.

Thanks and bye

Comment: *Don't* try to modify the `Date` values before posting. A `Date` has no format itself and JSON.stringify will correctly create an ISO8601 date string at UTC ie +00:00. ASP.NET can handle that correctly into a UTC DateTimeOffset.

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Do you mean the parseDateForSave method? I converted my dateString to a new date, but it still doesn't work.

Comment: A UTC time will always be 1 or 2 hours behind Berlin time. Are you sure you aren't misinterpreting UTC as local time? What does `dateString` contain?

Comment: parseDateForSave: 
ValidFrom: 2023-12-11T08:49
Database: 
ValidFrom:  2023-12-11 07:49:00.0000000 +00:00
LastUpdate (set in Backend): 2023-12-14 08:43:16.8098471 +01:00

I was hoping to get ValidFrom in the same format as LastUpdate.

Comment: The formats *are* the same. `ValidFrom` is a local time and doesn't have an offset though. It's probably the value of an `input type='datetime-local'`. You can convert it into a date directly with `new Date(dateString)`. This will produce a local time that's correctly serialized as ISO8601 at UTC

Comment: Thank you for your response! However, I am unsure about the meaning of DateTimeOffset.

Comment: You should avoid use of DateTimeOffset but rather Date object. UTC is much easier for handling time zone. See sample with ToUniversalTime and ToLocalTime here https://learn.microsoft.com/fr-fr/dotnet/api/system.datetime.utcnow?view=net-8.0

Comment: In addition, you have typescript helper for UTC into Date type : validFrom.toUTCString()

Comment: @PuygrenierSolann no, UTC isn't better than actually knowing the exact offset. Never mind that a DateTimeOffset at UTC has the exact same value as a DateTime with Kind=UTC. Never mind there's no way to specify that a `datetime2` field in the database is UTC, you have to make assumptions.

Comment: @PuygrenierSolann there's no reason to use `toUTCString` either, as a `Date` object is serialized to UTC. Just try it in your browser's console

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos - careful with that. `console.log` doesn't necessarily serialize in the same way as `JSON.stringify`.  Also there's no standard that controls what format `console.log` emits given a `Date` object.  See [whatwg/console#132](https://github.com/whatwg/console/issues/132).

Comment: @StackRescue - Before I attempt to answer, can I understand the use case please?  Does the user pick valid from/to as just dates? Or as dates and times? And are they expecting to enter these with regard to their _own_ time zone? Or specifically with regard to Berlin time, or UTC, or something else?  Also, you say you are using a `datetime-local` picker from Fluent UI, but I cannot find one.  Are you just using an `<input type="datetime-local">` HTML5 element? A link to the control's doc or example page would help. So would an [MVCE](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Comment: Also, is it SQL Server on the back-end with a `datetimeoffset` field? Or some other database or field type?  Are you using EF Core?

Comment: @PuygrenierSolann - `ToUniversalTime` and `DateTime.ToLocalTime` should be avoided in server-side code, as they will use the time zone of the server, which is usually not the time zone of the user (and is often UTC, making them a no-op).

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint I used JSon.stringify in Dev Tools console, not console.log. The real question is how `axios` serializes. I haven't used it (I use fetch) but I assume it's the same as JSON.stringify. There's a lot of information missing, so we have to make a lot of assumptions based on the symptoms.

Comment: Hello,

the user selects the date and time via a field. There are from and to fields.  I use:

<TextField
                    label="From"
                    type="datetime-local"
                    value={formatDateForDisplay(validFrom) || ''}
                    onChange={(_, newValue) => setValidFrom(newValue || '')}
                    styles={{root: {marginRight: '10px', flex: 1}}}
                />

The field in the database is a DateTimeOffset and EF Core is used. In my backend (when debugging) the time arrives without a time zone.

Comment: You missed a few of my questions.  Specifically, is the database MS SQL Server? Or something else like PostgreSQL or MySQL?  And - is the date and time the user picks specific to _their_ local time zone? Or specific to a single time zone like `Europe/Berlin`?  (even if they happen to be the same, it's still important to distinguish desired behavior)

Comment: @MattJohnson-Pint: It is an MS SQL server and the time zone selection should be specific to Europe/Berlin.